# Add something like a global variable to read it out from another form?

Tags: c#, variables, global

I'd like to create a program (or I already created it) which want's you to enter a name before the main form appears. The name which you enter should be saved as a variable. It's not that difficult, but if I want to retrieve it from another form, it's impossible, what to do?

I watched YouTube videos and searched on Google but I didn't find what I need.
I hope you can help.

Regards

Comment: You can create a class that gets passed to each form or you could have a static class that you can reference in each form? You have a number of ways to do this really. Do you know how to create classes?

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm a newbie at Visual C#

Comment: How do your forms relate to one another?  Does one create (instantiate) the other?

Comment: Ah right ok. Right click your project file and select add > class > give it a name. Think you should refer to this link at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287565(v=vs.71).aspx or even better I think you need to look at basic tutorials http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/SmartConsoleSetup.aspx.

Comment: I know how to create classes but I don't know what to do that I can retrieve a string variable from another class. What do you mean with "How do your forms relate to one another?" ? I created a project and two windows forms

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are a code smell - they are generally not a good idea (they make for brittle, untestable code).

In your case, if you have a reference to the second form, you can pass in data to it - you can add a property on this form and populate it.

```
// in Form2
public string Name { get; set; }

// in Form1 (frm2 is a reference to Form2)
frm2.Name = theName;
```

If the data is integral to the second form, an alternative is to create a constructor overload that takes the name as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public property on your form you will then be able to reference it from anywhere e.g.

```
public string MyProperty{get; set;};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have written the form class you can add a public property which you can use to set the name.

```
public partial class myForm : Form
{
    public String EnteredName { get; set; }

    public myForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
myForm f = new myForm();
f.EnteredName = "My Name";
f.ShowDialog();
```

This means you can do whatever you need to do within the form class.

N.B. don't call the property Name because it shadows the form's Name property.